# How to make a (nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) acts like (nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) in context of flex-direction: column CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox

You can see below the `div._b5a` is a flex container with  `flex-direction: column`.
However, normally its child is just a text sentence *([nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType))*: `新增個人簡介，讓大家更瞭解你` so the text sentence is still in the same line horizontally. That's the norm.

But after installing [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wanikani-highlighter/hombnkakdkackepmkogeoldikgigfeoh?hl=vi) in order to learn Kanji, it helped me by highlighting the Kanji's I want to learn. It highlights the text by wrapping it inside a `<mark style="background: green">`  (like the line 2 & 4 in the HTML snippet below). It works fine, until the case below when its parent is a flex container with `flex-direction: column`, it breaks the sentence into 3 lines instead of 1.

How can I fix it? *To highlight the text in this case, still keep the sentence in 1 line*. You can look at the code of the extension [here](https://github.com/Rickkwa/wanikani-highlighter/blob/master/js/highlight.js#L84-L94).

Hint: By adding

```css
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
```

to the `div` owns the sentence, it works adhocly for the case, but I'm not sure how to fix [the code from the extension](https://github.com/Rickkwa/wanikani-highlighter/blob/master/js/highlight.js#L84-L94) to make it work. (I'm bad at Jquery)

```css
._b5a {
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    /* flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center; */
}

div {
    display: block;
}
.fbTimelineUnit {
    color: #1c1e21;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="_b5a" style="text-align: center; opacity: 0.7;">新增個人簡介，讓
<mark class="wkh-hl" style="background-color: green; color: inherit;">
大
</mark>
家更瞭解你。</div>
```

Comment: Seems like you know the answer. If you want it to be in a single row and the parent is flex column you will need to somehow inject a flex row on top of the wrapped section. 
Basically, If a mark has been added. Inject a row to the content before and after, It seems like it would be complex to sort out all edge-cases, and when to clear the row (first period?) Especially in injecting into html.

Comment: @Jony-Y There're 2 places the extension uses the `wrapText` function are L22 and L41 of [this file](https://github.com/Rickkwa/wanikani-highlighter/blob/master/js/highlight.js). How can we check if the parent element only contains text *(nodeType==3)* whereas having `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`, then we convert it to `flex-direction: row; justify-content: (old.align-items == flex-start||flex-end) ? old.align-items : 'center'`? I want to change [the extension's original code](https://github.com/Rickkwa/wanikani-highlighter/blob/master/js/highlight.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing you can do is to set the display to `contents`, which will make the `mark` element in your question acts like a normal text node, but the trade off is that you lose the ability to style the container, which means you cannot style any container-related styles like `background-color`, `border`, `padding`...

But if you only want to highlight specific text. You can still use `color` or `font-weight` property to make the text more prominent. Here is an example

```css
._b5a {
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    /* flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center; */
}

div {
    display: block;
}
.fbTimelineUnit {
    color: #1c1e21;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

mark {
    display: contents;
    color: red !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="_b5a" style="text-align: center; opacity: 0.7;">新增個人簡介，讓
<mark class="wkh-hl" style="background-color: green; color: inherit;">
大
</mark>
家更瞭解你。</div>
```

Comment: Smort!, but https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents

Comment: I guess the only way to improve this answer is to wait :(